# Code is exiting without displaying any output

Tags: c#

I think it possibly has something to do with (ipCheck.Contains("TEXT")) But I am not sure exactly what is the source of the problem. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.
Why is my code exiting with the following error:

> The program '[8160] ConsoleApp5.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ip;

            Console.Write("Enter ip to check: ");
            ip = Console.ReadLine();
            WebClient w = new WebClient();
            string ipCheck = w.DownloadString("https://iphub.info/?ip=" + ip);
            if (ipCheck.Contains("Hosting/Proxy/Bad IP"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ip + " isn't a good ip, (Hosting/Proxy/Bad IP)");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (ipCheck.Contains("Good IP (residential or business)"))
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ip + " is a good IP Address, have fun ;)");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                    catch {Console.WriteLine("Error When Finding Information...(TRY REFORMATING YOUR IP)"); }
                Console.ReadLine();
                }
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Debug through the code, line by line. What happens?

Comment: Hint - `ipCheck` doesn't contain either of the two strings that you hoped it did.

Comment: Could you please provide "the following error:" ? (The message you've posted is standard trace reported when program exited successfully)

Comment: The website you're hitting requires executing javascript to get the information you want, and this type of web request won't run the page's javascript.

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on Selenium.

Comment: The code if failing before the try.  You will not get an output if this is false : ipCheck.Contains("Good IP (residential or business)")

Comment: Traditionally exit code 0 means the program terminated without error. If you have output you don't expect during the life of your program I suggest you throw an exception with the pertinent information or log it to console or some other medium. Never let your code do unexpected things silently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this isn't working is that the text "Good IP (residential or business" and "Hosting/Proxy/Bad IP" aren't actually in the response. The way this website works is using some JavaScript when the web page loads to check the IP address, which the web client doesn't do.

I recommend using a different IP checker that returns whether the IP address is good or bad in the HTML response. After a few minutes on Google I found this: https://www.whatismyip.com/ip-address-lookup/

NOTE: You also don't have all of the possible IP types. I also found the possibility of "Private".

Comment: Thanks, I am so dumb I should've looked at the response before I asked.